# How to use NLP to find out if two words have the same definition?

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot

If you see another question with the same wording as this, please ignore, it has unnecessary code

I made a very basic chatbot/program in Python that simulates ordering from a restaurant. I was wondering if there is any way to use Natural Language Processing (NLP) to find out if two words are the same? For example, how can NLP find out that "I'm feeling bad" means the same thing as "I'm feeling horrible" ?

Comment: One way is to use word embeddings, define some "closeness threshold", and check for words within that threshold. For something like this, you can use more classic word sense disambiguation approaches like wordnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your question is quite complex. By calculating the distance between word you can measure the distance between two word in an **Embedding space**, as known as **Word2Vec**, using something like euclidean distance, cosine similarity, and so on. (you can download pre-trained word2vec such as googlenews)

However, you mention about the similarity between **sentence** "I'm feeling bad" and **sentence** "I'm feeling horrible" which in this case it is easy, you just compare these two sentence and find out that they only have 1 part that is different which is the word "horrible" and "bad". Simplest way, you can use a vocab that contain set of synonyms to solve this. This is what we called **Rule-base system** (I suggest this rule-base method, something like nested of if-else).

Things will get more complicate when the sentence structure is different, now you need to have some kind of algorithm to detect not only word but also structure. You may need something like [WMD](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/kusnerb15.pdf) to measure similarity between sentence. Moreover, if you want to create a model that is not rule-base, you need **tons** of data, we called it **parallel corpus** which is just a pair of sentence that have similar meaning to train. For statistical method, you also need lots of data to calculate the probability but less than deep learning model.

Lastly,  do not look down toward rule-base method, this is what APPLE SIRI is using right now, **super huge** rule base. you can also add some complexity to your rule base while you are improving your model. Hope this answer your question